# Visual Studio is missing reference to COM dll

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, com

I have a project on C#. Furthemore I have a library that is developed on C++ and successfully built. I need to use that library in my C# project. So I registered C++ dll in COM and this is successfully registered and I can see it in registry in noe HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Wow6432Node/CLSID. 
When I add reference to that COM dll in my project it is missing and I can't see anything from that library. 
What the problem can be? Is it possible that if COM dll has any dependency and it require to reference it in my project?

Comment: You are adding a reference to the *type library* of the component.  The exact equivalent of metadata in a .NET assembly.  Normally embedded as a resource in a C++ component.  Something is amiss with it, you left no breadcrumbs to guess.  Use OleView.exe, File > View Typelib to get another opinion about it.  And verify that you registered it properly.

Comment: I've found that when I add this type library reference to my project it misses File path. Actually I can't understand why